# Asp.Net Core 2 issue with ViewComponent and Redis

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am playing with basic app, and I encounter an issue with Core 2.0 which I did not have in 1.1.

The site has a front-end and back-end api both on Core 2.0. The Layout of the front-end check if an entry exist on Redis (local install on Windows) to use to populate a navigation bar, if not it call the api, the api get the data, create the entry on redis with the data, and return the data to the front-end.

Everything works fine when accessing the view directly, but if one of the view use for example

```
return RedirectToAction("Blah2");
```

the redirect works fine however the server hangs when the viewcomponent is checking if the entry for the navigation bar exist in Redis. The views are :

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Blah1()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Blah2");
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Blah2()
{
    return View();
}
```

The check on Redis in the view component is

```
var value = await _redisCache.GetAsync(userid + "-NavBar");

if (value != null)
{
    List<VMNavBar> mynavs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VMNavBar>>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value));
    return View("Default", mynavs);
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

if I access the view "Blah2" directly it works, but if I access "Blah1", it blocks on **var value = await _redisCache.GetAsync(userid + "-NavBar");** and except stopping and restarting the front-end app, nothing works.

Any idea on why it blocks only if redirected, or how I can find why it blocks, I do not get any errors, the console does not give me anything

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:55554/Dashboard/User/blah1  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:55554/Dashboard/User/blah1  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method IRDevDashboardCore22.Areas.Dashboard.Controllers.UserController.Blah1 (IRDevDashboardCore22) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method IRDevDashboardCore22.Areas.Dashboard.Controllers.UserController.Blah1 (IRDevDashboardCore22) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult:Information: Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /Dashboard/User/Blah2.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult:Information: Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /Dashboard/User/Blah2.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action IRDevDashboardCore22.Areas.Dashboard.Controllers.UserController.Blah1 (IRDevDashboardCore22) in 26.7977ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action IRDevDashboardCore22.Areas.Dashboard.Controllers.UserController.Blah1 (IRDevDashboardCore22) in 26.7977ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 80.8103ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 80.8103ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:55554/Dashboard/User/Blah2  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:55554/Dashboard/User/Blah2  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method IRDevDashboardCore22.Areas.Dashboard.Controllers.UserController.Blah2 (IRDevDashboardCore22) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method IRDevDashboardCore22.Areas.Dashboard.Controllers.UserController.Blah2 (IRDevDashboardCore22) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor:Information: Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Areas/Dashboard/Views/User/Blah2.cshtml.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor:Information: Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Areas/Dashboard/Views/User/Blah2.cshtml.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it and I do not understand why it is the issue, if I go directly to the page it works but not if I am redirected to the page from another.

I had to change

```
var value = await _redisCache.GetAsync(userid + "-NavBar");
```

to

```
var value = await _redisCache.Get(userid + "-NavBar");
```

in the view component, kind of stupid to block on this.